# Вечная ошибка ninja: error: manifest 'build.ninja' still dirty after 100 tries

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

Установил CLion и после всех установок настроек по умолчанию. Код на C++:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Прилетает ошибка

```
[0/1] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/My programs/Test C++/cmake-build-debug
ninja: error: manifest 'build.ninja' still dirty after 100 tries
```

Пробовал синхронизировать время, но к решению проблемы не привело.
Вот код из CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(Test_C__)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

add_executable(Test_C__ main.cpp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Удалите директорию билда и .idea и пересоздайте проект, если синхронизация времени не помогла.

Comment: Не помогло, к сожалению, то же самое